# Selenium WebDriver for C# - Popup Dialog Boxes

Tags: c#, selenium, dialog, webdriver

Is there any support for working with popup dialogs (specifically file downloads) in c#?

Answer (score 3):

For a popup windows dialog, you can use the alert to catch:

```
IAlert alert = driver.SwitchTo().Alert();
alert.Accept();
```

Answer (score 2):

From the WebDriver FAQ: WebDriver offers the ability to cope with multiple windows. This is done by using the "WebDriver.switchTo().window()" method to switch to a window with a known name. If the name is not known, you can use "WebDriver.getWindowHandles()" to obtain a list of known windows. You may pass the handle to "switchTo().window()".

Full [FAQ](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_handle_pop_up_windows) here.

[Example](http://www.thoughtworks-studios.com/docs/twist/2.3/help/how_do_i_handle_popup_in_selenium2.html) from Thoughtworks

```
 String parentWindowHandle = browser.getWindowHandle(); // save the current window handle.
      WebDriver popup = null;
      Iterator<String> windowIterator = browser.getWindowHandles();
      while(windowIterator.hasNext()) { 
        String windowHandle = windowIterator.next(); 
        popup = browser.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
        if (popup.getTitle().equals("Google") {
          break;
        }
      }
```

Below is the example converted from Java into C# (with deprecated methods replaced)

```
        String parentWindowHandle = _browser.CurrentWindowHandle; // save the current window handle.
        IWebDriver popup = null;
        var  windowIterator = _browser.WindowHandles;

        foreach (var windowHandle in windowIterator)
        {
            popup = _browser.SwitchTo().Window(windowHandle);

            if (popup.Title == "Google")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't - at least not natively.

WebDriver only interacts with the webpage. A popup dialog, once instantiated, becomes the domain of the operating system instead of the webpage.

You can circumvent the file download/upload dialog by issuing a POST or a GET with the content you are retrieving or sending to the server.

You can use tools such as AutoIt, or the Windows Automation API, to interact with other dialog windows.