# close download popup window java

Tags: java, download, popup, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver in Java and I want to verify if is possible to download one document. When I click a link, its shown pup up download window and I need verify text from the title and close it. But I cannot click at the popup window and I don't know XPath etc. http://postimg.org/image/si2eagaqr/

```
driver.close(); this statement is useless for me
```

Can anyone advise me? I will be very grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Firefox the directly download the files - [File types and download actions](http://kb.mozillazine.org/File_types_and_download_actions)

If you don't want to hardcode the setting for your browser, you can setup a specific FF profile only for your tests, where you can configure where you want the files to be downloaded.

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\downloads");
firefoxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
```

I suggest you to use the first approach is much simpler.

Comment: thanks for response, but it is some way, how i can verify text in title?

Otevírání nameofcodument.doc

Comment: you can check the following discussion, I think it is the thing you are asking- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590803/selenium-webdriver-for-c-sharp-popup-dialog-boxes

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use robot for this purpose by pressing Enter please call the function below to press enter and it will press download button on UI . If this not works please let me know key sequence to perform this action .

```
public void pressEnter() throws AWTException, InterruptedException { 
Thread.sleep(5000);
 Robot rb=new Robot();
 rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
      rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); }
```

Comment: I don't think it is the best way to do it because if you run the tests on your machine if the focus of the cursor is on the email client, for example, this will submit the email.

Comment: it will work because when automatically alert box opens system focus shift to alert box please check it your self

Comment: I don't question that it will work, I'm just saying that there is a better way to do it, because of the mentioned reasons.